# Save Template disabled when sending email in Lightning

Tags: lightning, email, email-template, lightning-experience

When I try to send an email, I want to be able that after a proof-read, I do want to save the existing template, not as a new version.

[image]

Even if I am an administrator I can't save the template. Is there any configuation that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save as new template first. The option to save template will become available after you have **used (instered)** an existing template, which you can then edit and save.

Comment: The test doesn't depict this maybe, but it was chosen a particular template, and the Save Template option was still missing. The Salesforce support too didn't give a clear answer on what could cause this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

[This was disabled with the Summer '19 release.](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=release-notes.rn_cases_control_templates.htm&type=5&release=220)

> *... The Save as new template and Save template menu items are now unavailable to agents using the Email Quick Action when working on cases. Agents can still create and edit templates from the Email Templates home in Lightning Experience.*

> ***Where:** This change applies to Lightning Experience in Essentials, Professional, Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer editions.*

Comment: Welcome and good find! Even though the link states its disabled, it's always nice (as links break/pages move) to include a quote from the text stating so as opposed to just posting the link.